# Foreach lookup using keys to populate html table

Tags: knockout.js

I have some JSON data containing 2 arrays - column data and row data. The column data is specific and in the correct order, but the row data contains lots of data and does not match the order of the columns.

E.g.

```
Columns: A, B, C
Rows: D=1, C=2, A=2, B=1, F=3 etc. (approx 20 cols)
```

Are there are any high-performance methods for iterating over the columns & rows to produce an html table using Knockout?

The closest I have come is by using [knockout projections](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-projections) to map the row data, as per this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/fQZ6g/

I'm still using an arrayForEach inside it though. Are there any better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mbest/knockout-table. It is a very performant way to generate a table from column/row information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Ryan Niemeyer's suggestion, here's your example updated to use Knockout-Table:

```
<table data-bind="table: {
    columns: data().Columns,
    data: data().Rows,
    header: 'Label',
    dataItem: 'Key'
}"></table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/fQZ6g/8/

Comment: Most interesting. As it turns out I also need to do add some styles to the TH and TD, but didn't make this clear in the original question. However I do like this plugin and it seems pretty quick. Thanks.